Execute Javascript function inside of a tpl file
I'm trying to execute a javascript function inside of a tpl file but i dont exacly how to perform this.
i have a button in the tpl file :
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id=".sb-close-btn">Verder winkelen</span></button>

And the Js function that i want to perform is the close function of this JS function:
    $(document).on('click', '.sb-overlay, .sb-close-btn', function() {
        $('.sb-overlay').fadeOut('500');
        $('html').removeClass('sb-open');
        $('#scrolltopbtn').show();
    });

I tryed to add diferent id's to the tpl file and also include some parts of the javascript inside  tags without results

If you want to execute javascript on a TPL, you need to place the script between {literal} tags.

So it would look something like:
{literal}
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).on('click', '.sb-overlay, .sb-close-btn', function() {
        $('.sb-overlay').fadeOut('500');
        $('html').removeClass('sb-open');
        $('#scrolltopbtn').show();
    });
</script>
{/literal}

More info here >> https://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/language.function.literal

you should write it to be added at the end of a .tpl file, using the {literal} tag to ensure that the embedded JavaScript is not parsed by the template engine:
You can write like the below
{literal}
<script>
    $(document).on('click', '.sb-overlay, .sb-close-btn', function() {
        $('.sb-overlay').fadeOut('500');
        $('html').removeClass('sb-open');
        $('#scrolltopbtn').show();
    });
</script>

{literal} and {/literal} Tags: These tags ensure that the content between them is not parsed by the template engine, which is particularly useful when including JavaScript code in a template file.
<script> Tag: Used to include JavaScript code. Make sure it's placed correctly at the end of the .tpl file so that it loads after the rest of the page content.

Generally it's not a good idea, to write JS inside the .tpl files, it's better to create a custom.js and write your javascript functions there.
But yes you can write inside .tpl files as others stated with the {literal} tags.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
